# Haskell - Filtering Lists by Comparison

Tags: list, haskell, compare

I need to filter a list with a mask in Haskell.

It applies the function to an element of the mask list and the corresponding element in the data list, and if the function returns true, the corresponding element in the data list is included in the returned list.

For example, suppose I want to filter out data items that are greater than the mask items:

```
filtermask (\m d -> d > m) [1, 5, 7] [5, 6, 7]→[5, 6]
```

Any possible solution to this problem would be fantastic. So far, I've only done

```
 filtermask f m d = f m d
```

That returns TRUE

EDIT: Solution, thanks to help from Tikhon:

```
filtermask f [] [] = []
filtermask f (fm:rm) (fd:rd)
  |f fm fd = fd:filtermask f rm rd
  |otherwise = filtermask f rm rd
```

Comment: Does your mask and your data item, are always list and have both the same size ?

Comment: For my purposes, yes, they'll have the same size, and they'll be lists :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, what you want to do is first pair up each element of the mask with an element of the list. We can do this with `zip`, which gives us a list of pairs.

Now that we have a list of pairs, we want to filter this using the comparison function (`>`, or whatever). The `>` function has a type `Ord o => o -> o -> Bool`; we need to turn this into a function which accepts a tuple. Happily, we can do this with `uncurry`; `uncurry (>)` gives us a function of type `Ord o => (o, o) -> Bool`.

Since we already have a list of pairs, we can just use this function to filter it. Now we have a list of only the pairs we want to keep; we need to get a list of just the element. We can do this by mapping a projection function like `fst` over the list.

Putting it all together, we get:

```
filterMask :: (o -> o -> Bool) -> [o] -> [o] -> [o]
filterMask fn mask list = map fst (filter (uncurry fn) (zip list mask))
```

There's just one more subtle trick: what happens if the mask is shorter than our input list? With this function, the rest of the input list will be thrown out. If this is not what you want, you will need to repeat the mask. We can do this with a neat function called `cycle` which repeats a list forever. So that version would be:

```
filterMask fn mask list = map fst (filter (uncurry fn) (zip list (cycle mask)))
```

Comment: This was INCREDIBLY helpful in coming up with the solution that meets the requirements more accurately. Thank you so much, I learned a lot from your solution. I've edited the question to contain what the final accepted solution was for the project, and I've accepted your answer :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As you problem is design, two list of the same size, and a function working and their element, using the zip function is a good starting point. It's work like this,

```
# zip [1,2,3] [4,5,6] 
[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
```

Then, for each tuple, you have to check if the predicate is fill or not.
It's like to apply a zip **with** a function, there is a function for that.

```
# zipWith (\x y -> x + y) [1,2,3] [4,5,6] 
[5,7,9]
```

But, the applied function is a more than the one provided.
And, what are we supposed to do if the predicate is not satisfied ?
These two point are manage by a conditional statement and `Maybe` type.
Finally we obtain a list containing, two kind of value Nothing and Just x, and we'd like to keep the last one. `catMaybe` do the job.

```
# filtermask f m d = catMaybes $ zipWith (\x y -> if f x y then Just y else Nothing) m d
```

Comment: Awesome, that looks a lot like what the solution ended up being. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be broken down into two parts:

1. Producing the boolean mask from comparing the two lists
2. Filtering one of the lists based on the boolean mask

For 1, you can use `zipWith`. For 2, you can use `maskFilter`:

```
maskFilter :: [Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
maskFilter mask xs = [x | (m,x) <- zip mask xs, m]
```

For your example, you can use

```
let
    xs = [1,5,7]
    ys = [5,6,7]
    mask = zipWith (>) ys xs
in
    maskFilter mask ys
```